# pyOpenSSL X509 extension syntax error while adding authorityInfoAccess (AuthorityInfoAccessSyntax)

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, x509certificate, pyopenssl

I'm trying to add an authorityInfoAccess extension to an X509 Certificate using pyOpenSSL library version 0.13

**Running**

```
import OpenSSL
url = 'URI:https://localhost:12345'
ext = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension('authorityInfoAccess', 0, url)
cert.add_extensions([ext])
```

**Error**

```
('X509 V3 routines', 'V2I_AUTHORITY_INFO_ACCESS', 'invalid syntax')
('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')
```

So I tried various Syntax for my extension (doesn't work either):

```
'authorityInfoAccess:1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1;URI:https://localhost:12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around in documentations, I ended up into the OpenSSL doc:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/x509v3_config.html

And I found out that it is as simple as this:

```
'caIssuers;URI:https://localhost:12345'
```

The result in extensions is the following:

```
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
        CA:TRUE
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
        URI:urn:publicid:IDN+myCA:loic_baron+authority+sa, URI:urn:uuid:25f08be1-f79e-3572-b8ee-610344119bc9, email:loic.baron@domain.fr
    Authority Information Access: 
        CA Issuers - URI:https://localhost:12345
```